# Using a table alias/query expression in an Ecto fragment?

Tags: elixir, ecto, postgrex

Starting with this query as the basis for an Ecto version:

```
 select folder_id, json_agg(p.*) 
 from folder_memberships inner join profiles p 
 on p.id=folder_memberships.profile_id 
 where folder_id in (1234) group by folder_id;
```

I've got this code:

```
 # ids=[1234] 
 from(p in Profile,
   join: link in FolderMembership, on: link.profile_id == p.id,
   select: [link.folder_id, fragment("json_agg(?) as members", p)],
   group_by: link.folder_id,
   where: link.folder_id in ^ids
 ) 
 |> Repo.all
```

And that gets me the following error:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/profile.ex ==
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) variable `p` is not a valid query expression. 
Variables need to be explicitly interpolated in queries with ^
(ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.select/3
```

I'm sure I'm missing elementary but I'm bonkered if I know what it is. I've tried a number of options, but all the examples I've been able to see do something like `fragment("json_agg(?)", p.some_field)`, not `p` itself.

Comment: I thought `fragment("json_agg(?)", p.*)` would work but that escapes the `*` and ends up sending the value of the column named "*" to `json_agg`. I looked at all the tests in Ecto that include a `fragment` and didn't find any that pass a table name or `table.*`... I don't think this is possible with fragments right now.

Comment: Yep, tried that with the same result.  Ok, good to know its not just me. :) Will also give credit for answer to an alternate means of achieving the same result if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not perfect because it requires listing all fields explicitly and also doesn't let you exclude fields from the resulting JSON.

```
 # ids=[1234] 
 from(p in Profile,
   join: link in FolderMembership, on: link.profile_id == p.id,
   select: [link.folder_id, fragment("json_agg((?, ?, ?)::profiles) as members", p.id, p.name, p.created_at)],
   group_by: link.folder_id,
   where: link.folder_id in ^ids
 ) 
 |> Repo.all
```

The number of question marks in `json_agg` should be exactly the same as the number of columns in the profiles table and also the order of columns in the table should correspond to the order of `fragment` arguments. I don't know your schema, so I "made up" 3 columns - I hope you get the idea.

I tried this approach myself on a simplified example (without a join). The source code of the app I used as a playground is [there](https://github.com/DNNX/badging).

```
defmodule Magic do
  import Ecto.Query
  alias Badging.{Badge, Repo}

  @fields Badge.__schema__(:fields)
  @source Badge.__schema__(:source)
  @questions Enum.map_join(@fields, ", ", fn _ -> "?" end)
  @json_agg "json_agg((#{@questions})::#{@source})"

  def run do
    fields = Badge.__schema__(:fields)
    source = Badge.__schema__(:source)
    questions = Enum.map_join(fields, ", ", fn _ -> "?" end)
    json_agg = "json_agg((#{questions})::#{source})"

    from(
      b in Badge,
      select: [
        b.id,
        fragment(
          "json_agg((?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)::badges)",
          b.id,
          b.identifier,
          b.subject,
          b.status,
          b.color,
          b.svg,
          b.svg_downloaded_at,
          b.inserted_at,
          b.updated_at
        )
      ],
      group_by: b.id
    ) |> Repo.all
  end
end
```

I also made an attempt to make it more flexible by using `Badge.__schema__(:fields)` and `Badge.__schema__(:source)`, but stumbled upon [the inability of `fragment` to accept variable number of arguments](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1485).

This is what I got so far:

```
defmodule Magic do
  import Ecto.Query
  alias Badging.{Badge, Repo}

  fields = Badge.__schema__(:fields)
  source = Badge.__schema__(:source)
  questions = Enum.map_join(fields, ", ", fn _ -> "?" end)
  @json_agg "json_agg((#{questions})::#{@source})"

  def run do
    from(
      b in Badge,
      select: [
        b.id,
        fragment(
          @json_agg,
          field(b, :id), # or just b.id
          b.identifier,
          b.subject,
          b.status,
          b.color,
          b.svg,
          b.svg_downloaded_at,
          b.inserted_at,
          b.updated_at
        )
      ],
      group_by: b.id
    ) |> Repo.all
  end
end
```

I think *technically* it is possible to rely on `__schema__(:fields)` instead of listing all fields explicitly. The list of fields is known at compile time. I'm just not as good at macros in Elixir/Ecto to do it (yet).

Comment: Giving you credit for the answer even though its not quite the answer I was looking for—word from the ecto mailing list is that it should be supported, though it doesn't work at present. i actually spent about 5 hours yesterday trying to come up with a PR to support it but my metaprogramming skills in elixir aren't quite up to the task yet.